# Live server cannot get /index when extension is removed using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, visual-studio-code

Live server says "Cannot get /index" if I remove .html and .php extension from the URL, I am able to do that with xampp but I want to use live server. Any alternate method?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>         
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your htaccess file, please do mention urls(example of urls) which url is not working and what error are you getting for better understanding of question.

Comment: When I click on any hyperlink for example (./contact-us) it says cannot get whereas it works with xampp localhost

Comment: If you could give urls like `http://localhost:80/blabla` kind of which is NOT working along with what errors you are seeing, thank you.

Comment: The actual link when live server is loaded (working) : http://127.0.0.1:5500/
The link I am trying to open (Cannot GET /contact-us) : http://127.0.0.1:5500/contact-us

Comment: Ok this helps. So in backend contact-us page should be served by `index.php` file etc? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Nope, everything is html only right now